# Table formatting issues in react material UI

Tags: html, reactjs, material-ui

I am having issues making this inner table having full width and merged with all 8 columns.I could not get `colspan` to work with material UI and this inner table is collapsible which is functioning well but table formatting is the issue.

can anyone please help me to do above?

[image: This is my view right now]

Comment: If you provide me with your HTML / CSS / REACT code, i ll help you.

Answer (score 0):

I ll update this post if i get some more info from you. For now:

> can anyone please help me to do above?

Have you tried setting it to `width: 100%` ?

Here a [great guide for calibrating height / width.](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)